# Updating a node in linked list

Tags: c++

I want to update a data in the node of the linked list. I have tried to but it does not changed the data within. If anyone can help me with this, i would be really appreciated.

This is my Main Driver Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "item.h"

using namespace std;

LinkedList list;
Item item;
Node* node;

void menu()
{
here:
    int choice = 0;
    string itemId, title, type, loan, num_copy, fee, genre;
    cout << "Welcome to Genie\'s video store" << endl;
    cout << "Enter an option below" << endl;
    cout << "1. Add a new item" << endl;
    cout << "2. Delete an item" << endl;
    cout << "3. Update an item" << endl;
    cout << "4. Search an item by ID" << endl;
    cout << "5. Search an item by title" << endl;
    cout << "6. Display all item" << endl;
    cout << "Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        system("cls");
        list.addItem(list);
        cout << endl;
        goto here;
    }
    else if (choice == 2)
    {
        system("cls");
        list.deleteItem(list);
        cout << endl;
        goto here;
    }
    else if (choice == 3)
    {
        system("cls");
        list.updateItem(list);
        cout << endl;
        goto here;
    }
    else if (choice == 4)
    {
        system("cls");
        list.searchById(list);
        cout << endl;
        goto here;
    }
    else if (choice == 5)
    {
        system("cls");
        list.searchByTitle(list);
        cout << endl;
        goto here;
    }
    else if (choice == 6)
    {
        system("cls");
        list.printAll(list);
        cout << endl;
        goto here;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream file("items.txt", ios::in);
    if (!file)
    {
        cerr << "Error in opening file.";
        throw(file);
    }
    list.readAllFile(file, list);
    file.close();
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my item.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Item
{
protected:
    string itemId, title, type, loan, num_copy, fee, genre;
public:
    Item() {}
    Item(string itemId, string title, string type, string loan, string num_copy, string fee, string genre)
        : itemId(itemId), title(title), type(type), loan(loan), num_copy(num_copy), fee(fee), genre(genre)
    {}
    ~Item() {}
    string& getItemId() { return this->itemId; }
    string& getTitle() { return this->title; }
    string& getType() { return this->type; }
    string& getLoan() { return this->loan; }
    string& getCopy() { return this->num_copy; }
    string& getFee() { return this->fee; }
    string& getGenre() { return this->genre; }
    void setItemId(string itemId) { this->itemId = itemId; }
    void setTitle(string title) { this->title = title; }
    void setFee(string fee) { this->fee = fee; }
    void setCopy(string num_copy) { this->num_copy = num_copy; }
    void setLoan(string loan) { this->loan = loan; }
    void setType(string type) { this->type = type; }
    void setGenre(string genre) { this->genre = genre; }
};

class Node
{
private:
    Item data;
    Node* next;
public:
    Node() {}
    Node(Item newData)
    {
        data = newData;
        next = nullptr;
    }
    Node(Item newData, Node* nextNode)
    {
        data = newData;
        next = nextNode;
    }
    ~Node() {}
    Node* getNext() { return next; }
    void setNext(Node* newNext) { next = newNext; }
    Item getData() { return data; }
    Item setData(Item newData) { data = newData; }
    Node* createNode(Item newData);
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
public:
    LinkedList() : head(NULL), tail(NULL)
    {}
    ~LinkedList() {}
    void createList(LinkedList& list);
    void insertHead(LinkedList& list, Node* temp);
    void appenTail(LinkedList& list, Node* temp);
    void readLine(ifstream& file, Item& item);
    void readAllFile(ifstream& file, LinkedList& list);
    void printOneLine(Item item);
    void printAll(LinkedList list);
    //void writeToFile(LinkedList& list);
    void addItem(LinkedList& list);
    void deleteItem(LinkedList list);
    void updateItem(LinkedList& list);
    void searchById(LinkedList list);
    void searchByTitle(LinkedList list);
};
```

Finally, this is my item.cpp file:

```
void LinkedList::updateItem(LinkedList& list)
{
    string updateId, updateTitle, updateType, updateLoan, updateNumCopy, updateFee, updateGenre;
    Node node;
    Node* temp = list.head;
    bool found = false;
    if (temp == nullptr)
    {
        cerr << "There are no items." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Enter the item's id and other info you want to update below:" << endl;
    cout << "ID: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, updateId);
    cout << "Title: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, updateTitle);
    cout << "Type: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, updateType);
    cout << "Loan type: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, updateLoan);
    cout << "Copy(s): ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, updateNumCopy);
    cout << "Rental fee: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, updateFee);
    cout << "Rental genre: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, updateGenre);
    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        Item item = temp->getData();
        if ((_stricmp(item.getItemId().c_str(), updateId.c_str()) == 0) || (_stricmp(item.getTitle().c_str(), updateTitle.c_str()) == 0))
        {
            item.getItemId() = updateId;
            item.getTitle() = updateTitle;
            item.getType() = updateType;
            item.getLoan() = updateLoan;
            item.getFee() = updateFee;
            item.getGenre() = updateGenre;
            found = true;
        }
        temp = temp->getNext();
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        cerr << "Item not found." << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

So the main problem is that inside the updateItem() function, we do not know how to make the function to update a specific variables of the object. I have tried the above updateItem function and the final result is that none of the item's information is changed.

Thank you.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
Item item = temp->getData();
```

`getData` returns a copy and it is stored inside a new variable. You are making changes but it is not in the right variable. One solution would be to store and return a reference:

```cpp
// return a reference
Item & getData() { return data; }

// store a reference
Item & item = temp->getData();
```

Comment: Oh, i will try that. Thank you so much sir